# fencing or containment?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We have a couple questions about fencing and such relating to keeping a pet (dog mostly) in the yard.

[Do invisible fences pose long term health risks to dogs?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/749)

[How can I keep vermin out of outdoor pen or enclosure?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/273)

[Preventing dog from going to highway](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2489)

I don't see either a fencing or containment tag existing.  Currently I am leaning towards 'containment' being the primary tag, with 'fencing', 'run', 'pens' & 'cage' being synonyms.  ['cage'](https://pets.stackexchange.com/tags/cage/info) * ['pens'](https://pets.stackexchange.com/tags/pens/info) are existing tags.

Should we create the tag 'containment' and make it the primary tag, for all things related to keeping a pet in a confined area?

I am thinking this would include, small pets in cages in the house as well.

Comment: Tag away with containment and if alternates pop up, we can merge and make into synonyms.

Comment: Done ----------

Comment: Containment also covers avoiding the spreading of infectious diseases, in case we get such a question one day.

Comment: This seems sensible and well thought out James, containment does make the most sense here. In applications regarding infectious diseases, health-related tags would be more ideal than containment in general, I think.