# Containment vs. Enclosure (also sort of vs. Cage, Terrariums, and Crate) tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

There already was [fencing or containment?](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/712/fencing-or-containment) , but this is with two different tags that mean sort of the same thing, but are used synonymously, especially as regards fencing.

[containment](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/containment) and [enclosure](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enclosure)

For argument's sake, we also have [cage](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cage), which is used synonymously with [enclosure](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enclosure), especially as regards hutches.

I don't know if we should synonym these or not.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: keep all three tags, but make their tag wiki entries more distinct and make recommendations to each-other.

[containment](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/containment) regards questions about how to restrict a pet in some fashion, or restrict animals (including non-pets) from each other.

[enclosure](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enclosure) regards the actual device put in place to restrict a pet.

[cage](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cage) regards a smaller device put in place to restrict a pet, specifically, a cage.

**Evaluation of questions by tag (as of this posting):**

**containment : 20 questions**

[What is the right height & width for a cat's tunnel?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7230/what-is-the-right-height-width-for-a-cats-tunnel) - consider removing [containment](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/containment)

[What are the benefits and risks of a wire bottom cage for my pet rabbit?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/what-are-the-benefits-and-risks-of-a-wire-bottom-cage-for-my-pet-rabbit) - should be re-tagged [cage](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cage)

**enclosure : 8 questions**

[What spurs a tortoise to try to climb out of its enclosure?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/3320/what-spurs-a-tortoise-to-try-to-climb-out-of-its-enclosure) - add [containment](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/containment)

[How can I protect my chickens' eggs from snakes?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/954/how-can-i-protect-my-chickens-eggs-from-snakes) - consider removing [care](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/care), adding [containment](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/containment)

**cage : 10 questions**

[Can a hamster and a tortoise/land turtle coexist peacefully?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2941/can-a-hamster-and-a-tortoise-land-turtle-coexist-peacefully) - possible re-tag to [enclosure](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enclosure) or removal of [cage](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cage)

[Is it safe to use tung oil to waterproof a rabbit enclosure?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2025/is-it-safe-to-use-tung-oil-to-waterproof-a-rabbit-enclosure) - remove [cage](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cage), re-tag to [enclosure](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enclosure)

**terrariums : 13 questions**

No issues.

Comment: I'd say the snake question just needs [snakes][health][skin-conditions] since the focus of the question is the snake's condition. Also, snakes would live in terrariums technically.

Comment: @MattS. Please feel free to edit my answer to reflect any changes made, remove questions if necessary.

Comment: I've updated my answer and several questions, as well as the tag wiki for Containment.  The tags on the questions that remain may need revision. Also will need to know where rabbit hutches should go: cages or enclosures?  Will need a rabbit expert's input.  !summon @JamesJenkins

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference is between cage and enclosure? Can you clarify that?

Comment: @Zaralynda - I didn't make the tags.  I can only assume an enclosure represents a contained "area" such as a pen, walled or fenced land, or larger "area", whereas a "cage" may represents a fully barred container, perhaps for a rodent?

Comment: I just wonder if cage and enclosure (and maybe terrarium) should be synonyms

Comment: @Zaralynda - no.  There is definitely a difference between questions that would have to do with fencing / large tortoise-style habitats (enclosures) and pens, vs handheld cages for rodents.

Comment: If you believe they should be separate, can you clarify the differences?

Comment: I just did.  enclosures: large; fencing, pens, generally outdoor habitats; can have bars like monkey pens; cages: small crate things with bars on them, made of metal, sometimes plastic, generally used for rodents.

Comment: @Zaralynda Cages have wire/metal bars, and terrariums are typically made of glass (sometimes some sides are wood). I think "containment" and "enclosure" could be used for various types of small pet environments (in other words, a superset of cages and terrariums), but after reading Josh's comments I can see the case for "enclosure" being a sort of pen rather than a smaller environment.

Comment: @Zaralynda If you want to lump them in together, you could make cage, enclosure, hutch, terrarium and aquarium synonyms that all map to something like `small-pet-environment`. Not sure whether it's better to keep them together or not though.

Comment: I think keeping terrarium separate is important since those are directly related to each other.